Can a company be fined in a value larger than the global GDP?
This article below says that Google has been fined $20 decillion USD in Russia due to a failure to reinstate state-owned YouTube channels: Russian court fines Google $20,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
Why this is even possible? This value is around 1,000 times (I think) larger than the entire global GDP.

Re: "is around 1,000 times … larger", correction suggested: World's GDP is roughly $100 trillion (1*10^14). $20 decillion is 2*10^34, which is 2*10^20 (200,000,000,000,000,000,000 or two hundred quintillion) times larger than the combined GDP of an Earth-like civilization.

It's certainly possible to order such a fine. However, the possibility of collecting such a fine (or, in this case, any fine) is a very different matter. Sovereign nations can make whatever laws and issues whatever orders under those laws they want. However, their ability to enforce such orders outside of their borders is an entirely different matter and only tangentially related to law. About the only way Russia will collect this fine is if the United States prints 2 undecillion counterfeit rubles and hands them to Google to pay the fine and obliterate Russia's entire economy.

Note the following sentence your linkd article: "The court imposed a fine of 100 thousand rubles ($1,025) per day, with the total fine doubling every week." I'm fairly sure this is perfectly legal and I think such daily increasing fines are used in other contexts as well. They are usually paid off quickly, which is the whole point of the increasing fine.

@quarague Daily increasing fines are one thing. Weekly multiplying ones are quite another. Granted, a sovereign nation can still do that. And someone outside of its jurisdiction can still ignore it.

"Why this is even possible?" You're assuming that a legal system makes sense. Few of them manage that consistently, but ones in a dictatorship hardly ever.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Of course. Google could pay it off for a long time.
There are often cases where either a prison sentence vastly exceeds human life expectancy or where a fine exceeds the ability of the convict to pay. There are two possible reasons for this:

The court wants to make sure that even if the sentence is reduced later on, the reduction happens from a very high baseline. To give a simple and almost-reasonable example, say a release for good conduct is possible after half the sentence in some jurisdiction. If everybody knows this, then "four years" would be understood as "two years, with good conduct."
The legal system adds multiple parts of the sentence, like "twice ten years, served consecutively" becoming "twenty years." Each individual sentence attempts to be fair and then simple, heartless arithmetic takes over. By contrast, see the German system where multiple terms are turned into "more than the largest single sentence, no more than the sum of all sentences, and in any case no more than 15 years."

Or it is all theatrics, and everybody knows it is all theatrics.

Perhaps Google will suggest paying one dollar per year?

@JonCuster: Perhaps Google will declare the US government forbids paying any fine; which leads to a very different kind of question.

@Joshua, that should not change a thing. If Russia fines Google, Russia can confiscate Google assets in their jurisdiction and request other jurisdictions to help. That cooperation is not automatic, even among largely allied nations.

@o.m. Which assets in Russia? Goggle LLC (Russia) has filed for bankruptcy 2 years ago (in 2022) with debts of 19 billion rubels and only 3-ish billion rubels assets. The rest of Alphabet group is geofencing and blocking account creation from Russia. Almost no country but Russia willingly enforces a judgment from Russia.

Now now, I suspect that North Korea is more than willing to seize all of Google's assets in ... ummm ... wait ... well, I guess they won't get much...

I remember of a killer somewhere in the USA found guilty of murdering five children. The jury inquired and found out that with a life sentence you might get parole. For a fixed term sentence one third must be served before parole is possible. They give him 5,000 years for each murdered child = 25,000 years. He can apply for parole after 8.333 years and 4 months.

Unrelated to the topic but about the formatting, the word "long" in the first line is not italicized. I'd assume you wanted to emphasize that, but the whole line itself is already emphasized. If that's the case, then either needs to be bold.

@AndrewT., I encountered "double italics means no italics" before and liked it better than "double italics is bold italics." Generally, I find bold much more emphatic, often too empathic.

@gnasher729 Did you switch from comma thousands separators to period thousands separators?

@JonCuster Haha, classic reverse Dogbert!

As the article itself states:

The court imposed a fine of 100 thousand rubles ($1,025) per day, with the total fine doubling every week

This is the apocryphal wheat on a chessboard story coming to life. In the original story, the inventor of chess supposedly asked for one grain were placed on the first square, two on the second, four on the third, and so on, doubling every square of the board. The chessboard has 64 pieces, and the theoretical fine has doubled over 104 weeks.
Legally, the fine is still only 100,000 rubles. By paying that, Google can declare they've paid it. There is no enforcement mechanism for any fines not spelled out as a specific number, other than a new trial, where the original judgement will be re-examined.
If there is trial about the exact amount due, civil law usually restricts late payment penalties to 0.1% per day. Russian law seems to follow this rule, with possibly an even stricter 20% per annum limit.
Assuming the war ends by October 23, 2077, the fine by then will be $28.6 billion under the 0.1% per day rule, or a disappointing $23.2 million under the 20% p.a. limit. If, on the other hand, the doubling per week rule holds, the fine will be 2.26e+863, or 226 sexoctogintaducentillion. You will need a cookie clicker expert to spell it out properly.
And if this judgement was a deliberate joke on Google's name, we can estimate that the fine will reach 1 googol or 10^100 rubles by November 20, 2029.

Important distinction: is the fine in rubles or dollars? Perhaps with rampant enough inflation/devaluation, a googol ruble fine could be reasonably payable in 2029

It's an interesting post, but it doesn't answer the question. What's the legal mechanism under which a company can be fined such a large amount in Russia? Also, your link to the 20% limit has nothing to do with the question: it's about penalties for late loan repayments, not court imposed fines.

@JBentley There is no legal mechanism. The fine is ~$1,000, and the addendum about doubling it weekly is contrary to established practice for late payment penalties, which means it would most likely not be respected in a new trial against a new legal entity, should Google return to Russia.

@Therac What matters isn't "established practice" but what the actual law says that the courts in Russia can impose as a fine. If you think that the court's ruling was unlawful then you should make that your answer together with a citation which backs up your claim (for example a piece of legislation which puts a cap on the amount of the fine for such cases, or some other authoritative source of law). As things stand there is nothing in your answer which is of any relevance to the question from a legal perspective.

@JBentley What's legally important is that the decillion-dollar fine doesn't exist. The fine is $1,025, Google can simply pay that and declare themselves in the clear. A prosecutor can come after them, based on a mathematical interpretation of the original verdict, but that's a moot point: if the war ends, the state will just tell them to stand down.

@CriticizingSEisbannable This is law stackexchange, so we're only concerned with the legal aspect here.

@Therac If your claim is now that "the decillion-dollar fine doesn't exist" (i.e. you are claiming that the media articles are wrong in the way they described the judgment) then you should cite the parts of the judgment which show that. So far you just seem to be giving various personal opinions but without any legal substance.

@Therac Capital punishment is also not allowed in Russia, and yet Navalny is still dead.

@JBentley Since there's no decillion dollar fine in any of the original documents, it's on the media to prove its existence. Otherwise it's no more real than the right to shoot Scotsmen with arrows - based in a modern reinterpretation of a narrowly specific local wartime law. Short of that, it's simply a viral meme.

@Therac No, its on you to prove your claim, since you are the one posting it as an answer on law stackexchange. Otherwise it's just the unsubstantiated claim of a random person on the internet. If there is no decillion dollar fine then you can trivially prove it by linking to the judgment that you've taken that information from. The fact that you aren't doing so despite multiple requests tends to suggest that you can't because your claim is false. But I'm happy to be shown to be wrong.
